# ¿Cuál es el origen de la palabra "chilango"?

Tags: etimología, significado, historia, coloquialismos, méxico

En México se utiliza el término "chilango" para referirse a las personas originarias del Distrito Federal.

¿Cuál es la etimología de la palabra "chilango"? ¿De dónde se origina?

Comment: No es cierto, al de ciudad es capitalino y anterior era Defeño, chilango es el que viene de provincia vive en la ciudad, tiene un hijo y su hijo es chilango. Que el mal uso, le estén dando otro significado es diferente y no me gusta que me digan chilanga, por qué en sonora ya me querían linchar por ser chilanga según ellos y es un término mal usado.

Comment: Una explicación que leí hace algún tiempo decía que:
Chilango es la persona nacida en la Ciudad de México, pero de padres nacidos en otros sitios del país, como es mi madre nacida en Tamaulipas y mi padre nacido en Tabasco por ejemplo...
Y defeño es la persona nacida en la Ciudad de México, cuyos padres son nacidos en la misma Ciudad de México...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El [DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/chilango) recoge el significado actual de “chilango” como un adjetivo coloquial que hace referencia a una persona natural del Distrito Federal, México, así como a cualquier cosa relativa o perteneciente a esa ciudad.

Ahora bien, dado que el origen de ésta palabra es *oscuro*, en gran parte por ser (aparentemente) muy antiguo (posiblemente original de la época prehispánica en México), existen varias teorías encaminadas a explicar el origen de la misma.

Aquí una breve descripción de las explicaciones que he encontrado en una búsqueda por internet:

> "…según el ensayista mexicano Gabriel Zaid, proviene del vocablo maya
>   *xilaan*, que significa ‘de pelo revuelto’, ‘desgreñado’ o ‘encrespado’.
>   Según esta teoría, la palabra era usual entre los veracruzanos para
>   hacer referencia a los naturales de Ciudad de México."
>
> "…tiene su voz náhuatl *chilan-co*, que traduciría ‘de piel colorada’, en
>   alusión al color de piel de los indígenas aztecas, enrojecida debido
>   al frío de la altiplanicie."
>
> "…se dio en llamar así a los presos que eran llevados a la cárcel de
>   San Juan de Ulúa, sita en Veracruz, durante las épocas posteriores a
>   la Independencia. Y es que los mismos iban atados en grupo de una
>   forma similar a la que se ataban los chiles que se vendían y que se
>   presentan en manojos, a los que se les llamada chilangas."
>
> "…tiene su origen en los vendedores de chile que en el pasado vendían
>   en el mercado y que utilizaban una forma de hablar que parecía que
>   cantaban."

Cabe mencionar que aunque el uso de ésta palabra es considerado, en general, despectivo, también se ha convertido en un rasgo de identidad para los capitalinos, que más allá de sentirse despreciados por el término, les enorgullece, por lo menos desde mi punto de vista.

Yo añadiría que ser *chilango* no es solamente nacer en el D. F., sino que hay que vivir ahí y adoptar su forma de vida para ser considerado como tal, ya que  yo que he nacido ahí no me considero *chilango* dado que emigré apenas siendo un crío.

Aquí las fuentes más relevantes:

http://www.significados.com/chilango/

http://definicion.de/chilango/

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chilango

Answer (score 0):

Si le preguntaras a una persona de cualquier parte de México. ¿Qué significa la palabra "Chilango"?, lo único que te dicen en concordancia y a voz populi es "El chilango es un hijo de la chingada" y es la única frase que concuerda con todos, de allí que la palabra chilango se deriva del verbo “chingar”. Así que solo falta saber quién era la chingada.

La chingada es una nativa oriunda de la nueva España violada por un extranjero del viejo continente (Normalmente un español), si esta quedaba embarazada se quedaba chingada y al producto se le llama chilango, de allí el término “Es un hijo de la chingada”.

Es despectiva porque si la expresión “chinga tu madre” es la mas o una de las más fuertes en México es un hecho que falta por hacerse y el que le digan a uno “chilango” es un hecho consumado, por eso en esos tiempos habían gente que sacaba un arma y mataba al que se lo dijo, dicho en otras palabras “Eres un bastardo mestizo hijo de una india violada”, (si la expresión se suaviza no se entiende el despecho tan fuerte y pierde el sentido).

Los chilangos nacían en comunidades indígenas que al nacer eran odiados por toda la comunidad, por el hecho de haber nacido por una violación, incluyendo Padrastro medios-hermanos abuelos cacique etc. Así que eran repudiados por los lugareños y no podían convivir con la comunidad no les daban estudios así que parecían retrasados o mensos con pocos conocimientos, De estos 2 atributos (Retrasados o mensos y odiados u odiosos), son los atributos que después se utilizaron para definir en un principio al resto de la república de la ciudad de México por la ciudad de México y posteriormente el resto de la república hacia los habitantes de la ciudad de México. (Hablando de México como república Mexicana. Ya que también fueron provincias anteriormente y el termino “chilango” nace cuando eran provincias. Antes de la independencia y/ o revolución Mexicana). Es obvio que al crecer los chilangos se salían de las comunidades nativas, tampoco eran bien recibidos en los poblados españoles.

Hubo un tiempo en el cual la tecnología los conocimientos y la comunicación de la ciudad de México se acelero bastante dejando muy atrasados a demás poblados, todos los adelantos mundiales entraban por la ciudad y el único aeropuerto internacional de México demás de un incremento en la ciudad de gente y familias que se iban a vivir a la ciudad de México en busca de mejores oportunidades de trabajo, cuando estas personas en sus vacaciones visitaban a sus parientes de donde venían alardeaban las novedades de la ciudad y también empezaron a ver ciertos atrasos en sus lugares de origen en los que parecían mensos o retrasados a los que visitaban a tal grado que les dieron el apodo de chilangos (Pero sí parecen chilangos por mensos). Con el tiempo ya no aguantaban a la gente que los visitaban y le cambiaron el sentido (Los chilangos son ustedes por odiosos). Por eso el término se les aplica a ciertos habitantes de la ciudad y no a los oriundos de dicha ciudad.

En la actualidad con los medios de comunicación casi inmediatos y el internet ya no existe ese atraso de tecnologías y novedades.

Comment: Hola, gracias por la respuesta. Entra en contradicción con las otras respuetas, ¿podrías aportar referencias que sustenten tu hipótesis? Dale a [edit] para añadirlas, ¡gracias!

Comment: Muy interesante todo esto pero chin**ga**da y chi**lan**ga me parecen bastante diferentes....