# ¿Cómo se abrevia Distrito Federal al mencionar México?

Tags: méxico, puntuación, abreviaturas, topónimos

Estaba leyendo la [respuesta de Jose Maria](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/14919/1674) a [¿Cuál es la historia de la palabra “chilango”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/14914/1674) cuando me fijé en la parte de:

> Yo añadiría que ser chilango no es solamente nacer en el **D.F.**,
>   sino que hay que...

Me sorprendió este `D.F.` en lugar de simplemente `DF`. En busca de un esclarecimiento, entré en la [web del Distrito Federal](http://www.df.gob.mx/) pero no pude encontrar una respuesta.

Mi pregunta es: ¿decimos "D.F." o "DF"? ¿Hay alguna regla al respecto o depende de cada localidad?

Comment: Creo que es una abreviatura de "Distrito Federal"

Comment: Y las abreviaturas van separadas por punto siempre

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Según la RAE, cuando se forma una [abreviatura](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=abreviatura) usando las iniciales de las palabras que forman una fórmula o expresión, éstas deben ir seguidas de punto, y tras un punto siempre se debe dejar un espacio. Por tanto, la abreviatura correcta para Distrito Federal es *D. F.*

Como confirmación, esta abreviatura aparece en la [lista de abreviaturas más frecuentes](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/apendices/apendice2.html) incluida como apéndice del Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas.

Hoy día, de todos modos, es bastante habitual pronunciar *de efe*, con lo cual se ha convertido la antigua abreviatura en [sigla](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=sigla). En ese caso, lo correcto es escribir todo junto *DF*, sin puntos.

En resumen, y según la norma:

- Si se pronuncia *Distrito Federal*, se debe escribir *D. F.*
- Si se pronuncia *De Efe*, se debe escribir *DF*
- *D.F.*, sin espacios, es incorrecto en cualquier caso

Comment: ¡Caramba, pero si además debe llevar espacio entre `D.` y `F.`!

Comment: @fedorqui Qué cosas, ¿verdad? De todos modos, he mejorado un poco la respuesta, que antes estaba coja.

Comment: Uhms, la respuesta es tan completa que me hace surgir otra: ¿y con qué opción hay que quedarse? : ) Supongo que en un contexto formal debería ser `D. F.`

Comment: Sí. Llamar *deefe* a México, D. F. es un uso coloquial. Aunque ahora vendrá algún mexicano y me corregirá, quién sabe :)

Comment: ¡Gracias! (Nótese que "tan completa" no era para nada un comentario negativo, sino positivo; releyéndolo me sonó mal)

Comment: Huy, no me había sonado negativo para nada. Me lo había tomado como un elogio y te lo agradezco.

Comment: ¡Válgame! Lo he escrito mal toda la vida. Gracias por el dato @Gorpik.